# c# winform combobox different display

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am using `Visual Studio 2010` and `.NET 3.5` and I am seeing a `combobox` display differently in different project.  I drop in the `combobox` the same way from the toolbox and change the `dropdownstyle` to `DropDownList`.  But depending on the project, the `combobox` may look like it is indented (similar look as in `DropDown`), with the field highlighted in blue.  But in the other project, the `combobox` has a more 3D feel. I would love to provide a screenshot but I don't have enough reputation to post images. :-(  I am guessing it's probably due to some project settings maybe?  Because I create the `combobox` the exact same way in both projects - I added a new `Form` and drop a `combobox` on the form and change the `dropdownstyle` to `DropDownList`; however, they look differently in the dialog when the project is run.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the FlatStyle property?

Comment: You can always peek in the designer file (but don't manually change things there) and see what the differences are.

Comment: you can upload your screenshot but it will display as a link

Comment: I try to upload but when save it says I can't because I don't have enough reputation.  It's their scam prevention scheme apparently.

Comment: Tried the FlatStyle, but didn't work

Comment: The two form's designer.cs are identical except for the namespace differences of course.

Answer (score 1):

Solve my own problem.  Somehow Application.EnableVisualStyles();   was removed in program.cs.  Once I added Application.EnableVisualStyles();  before calling the main form, the comobobox looks the way I wanted